# Mathplotlib won't plot within IPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython

I wanted to plot a pretty basic graph I found somewhere on a website with the following code:

```
%matplotlib inline

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([0, 1, 2, 5])
plt.show()
```

But it has this result:

```
<Figure size 432x288 with 1 Axes>
```

And not a pretty graph, what went wrong?
I did install matplotlib via pip in my command prompt.

Comment: If you're using IPython in a text terminal or console, it won't be able to show you graphs... You probably want Jupyter Notebooks, which run in your browser and will display graphs. See https://jupyter.org/ for details and how to install it.

Comment: @filbranden Well, how did we do it before jupyter existed? The point is just that you cannot use `inline` as backend. `%matplotlib qt` or `%matplotlib tk` would work I suppose.